# Excel Chart Titles - can I format parts of the title using cell reference such as Sheet1!$A$1?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

I have a chart in Excel with the Title linked to a cell `=REPORT_PAGE!$A$1`
The formula in A1 looks like this:
`=ProductName & ": Project Performance" & CHAR(10) & 
"SPI: " & TEXT(VLOOKUP(TODAY(),ProjectData,13,TRUE),"0#.0#") & CHAR(10) & 
"EV: " & TEXT(VLOOKUP(TODAY(),ProjectData,11,TRUE),"#.0#%") & CHAR(10) & 
"PV: " & TEXT(VLOOKUP(TODAY(),ProjectData,12,TRUE),"#.0#%")`

This provides a Title which is all the same size; something like this:

> **BIG CHART TITLE
>
>   BIG METRIC 1
>
>   BIG METRIC 2
>
>   BIG METRIC 3**

I need something that can change the title to look more like this:

> **BIG CHART TITLE**
>   small-font metric 1
>   small-font metric 2
>   small-font metric 3

I would like to do this without VBA if possible.

Comment: check out [Paste Picture Links](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/10/19/how-to-use-picture-links/). You can create the title in 4 rows of cells, format them as needed, then paste them as a picture link onto the chart as the title. You can then place position where you want it and group picture and chart together so they move in unison. Turn on VBA recorder to learn code behind it.

Comment: Scott - I read the article but not sure that I understand how to place that in the title of a chart using the Paste Link Picture.  Someone on SE SuperUser insisted that VBA is required so I may be forced that route.

Comment: SammyB - It's a separate object that you lay over the chart. You still may need VBA to accomplish this, but maybe not. I am not sure of your exact setup. In other words, instead of using an "actual chart title" (as in the title object), you place the picture link where the "actual chart title" object would go.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  I got it to work but I'll need the VBA to make it into the "Title."  Part of the detail that i left out is that the title is the only overlay that works in SharePoint which is where the charts are being published.  I'm on the right track though.  Can you post your comments as an  answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Paste Picture Links](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/10/19/how-to-use-picture-links/)

1. Create the title in 4 rows of cells
2. Format them as needed
3. Paste them as a picture link onto the chart where the title would go (do not use the actual title object in the chart.
4. Optional - Position the picture link where you want and group it with the chart so they move in unison.